# after validation return empty field with focus

Tags: php, jquery, validation, focus

I have an application which has a validation on pincode.
When validation is wrong is displays the error message, but then it keeps the pincode in the field and it looses focus.
when you first enter upon the modal to enter the pincode it focusses alright and opens the modal keyboard. I want the same when you have to fill in the pincode again.
below code is for focussing and the validation:

the validation:

```
    $('#suspend_sale').click(function() {
        var custID  = $("#spos_customer").val(),
            pin     = $("#reference_note").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + 'customers/validatePin',
        data: {
            custID: custID,
            pin: pin
        },
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.valid) {
                $('#hold_ref').val($('#reference_note').val());
                $('#total_items').val(an - 1);
                $('#total_quantity').val(count - 1);
                $('#submit').click();
            } else {
                $("#ref_error_msg").show(function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#ref_error_msg").hide('slow');
                    }, 1000);
                });
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            bootbox.alert(lang.customer_request_failed);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

first focus on the input field:

```
    $('#susModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // clear input field, set focus and click to make keyboard appear
    $('#reference_note').val('').focus().click();
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Just change in your jquery like this . remove click()

```
   $('#susModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
// clear input field, set focus and click to make keyboard appear
$('#reference_note').val('');
$('#reference_note').focus();
```

});

working fine

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add 1 extra line:

```
else {
     $("#ref_error_msg").show(function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
             $("#ref_error_msg").hide('slow');
         }, 1000);
     });
     //after showing the error message you need to clear the input & focus upon it
     $('#reference_note').val('').focus();
}
```